# Visual C++ 2010 SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

As a C++ developer using Visual Studio 2010, what do I gain from installing SP1 (that is related to C++)? Any significant language/library changes related to C++0x/TR1? Or is SP1 mostly a bugfix release?

Comment: The MS service packs are always bug fixes. Their policy is to never change features without also changing the version.

Comment: @Bo Persson, disagree. A service pack to VS 2008 rolled up the Feature Pack that included SIGNIFICANT C++ functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KB983509](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) lists the changes in SP1. There's nothing  0x-related (or just bugs, but I'm too lazy to go over that list).

Answer (score 3):

VS 2010 SP1 fixes one real nasty bug filed here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564917#

That bug alone was enough for me to install SP1.

Answer (score 2):

It fixes the really bad bug of "Crash on Show All Files". It *supposedly* fixes the "Crash on Close" bug but it still happens on my machine. Not terribly nice but it's not hurting anything as the program has already closed.